# How do I disable the keyboard shortcut for Globe/Fn-E? I don't want the emoji keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I have already set Settings> Keyboard> Press [Globe/Fn] key to... Do Nothing.

Now I have the problem that I'm hitting `Fn-E` when I try to type `Ctrl-E` in the terminal, and... again... the stupid emoji window pops up.

How do I disable the `Fn-E` shortcut? I can't find it anywhere in Settings> Keyboard> Keyboard Shortcuts...

(Gosh, it would be useful to be able to search for it by clicking on a 'search by keypress' area and pressing the hotkey combination, the way that IntelliJ provides.)

I tried creating a 'Do nothing' Quick Action in Automator, quitting Settings so it would notice the new thing, re-entering the keyboard shortcut Settings, finding it in Services> General, and then trying to associate it with the `Fn-E` shortcut, but it just went 'beep' at me. Didn't even say 'Haha, you can't override Apple'.

Comment: I removed your rant about Apple as (1) this is not a discussion board and (2) they tend to be of-putting. We all understand being annoyed with Apple as many of us have been working on or supporting Apple products for much (if not all) of our careers. We are happy to assist you with your issues, but the rants belong on Reddit or other such place.

Comment: Try creating a different shortcut for that menu item    https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-keyboard-shortcuts-for-apps-mchlp2271/mac#:~:text=On%20your%20Mac%2C%20choose%20Apple,Keyboard%20Shortcuts%20on%20the%20right.&text=Select%20App%20Shortcuts%20on%20the,specific%20app%20or%20All%20Applications.

Comment: This might end up being one for [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org) Fn has a history of being fairly intractable.